# Is there a way to guarantee the order in which BroadcastReceivers receive a single Intent?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I would like to send out an Intent to 2 BroadcastReceivers, A and B in which A receives the Intent before B. It appears to me that the order the BroadcastReceivers are registered is the order that they will receive the Intent.

For example:

```
        registerReceiver(A, filter);
        registerReceiver(B, filter);
```

Will this cause A to receive the relevant Intent before B? This is the behavior I am seeing, but I am not sure it is guaranteed.

Is this guaranteed or is it luck?

Comment: With `sendBroadcast()`, delivery is unordered and I would not recommend relying upon any particular order. With `sendOrderedBroadcast()`, it is ordered, with [the `IntentFilter` priority](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter?hl=en#setPriority(int)) determining the order. Also, if this is all within a single app process, please consider using something other than broadcasts, for privacy and performance reasons.

Comment: I need to send Broadcasts from notification buttons to Activity components. I also need them to send Broadcasts from a Service to Activity components. What do you suggest I use?

Comment: "I also need them to send Broadcasts from a Service to Activity components" -- if they are in the same process, you do not. Broadcasts, like other forms of IPC, are for between processes, including between apps and between system components (e.g., the notification system) and apps.